# grammar question with need

Tags: grammar

I would like to know what ...... for this job.

1. A) qualifications I need to be applied

   B) qualifications I need being  applied

   C) qualifications to be applied I need

   Please help, if anyone knows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your sentence and break it down:

> I would like to know what [*something about qualifications needed*] for this job.

Let's ignore, for the moment the *why* of it and get to the nitty-gritty -- you want to know something:

> I would like to know what *X*.

What is it that you would like to know?  You want to know what qualifications you need:

> I would like to know what *qualifications I need*.

Note that if you aren't the person applying for the position or if you prefer a little less personal style, you could also say:

> I would like to know what *qualifications are needed*.

Now, the person reading this may be wondering what you're talking about -- qualifications to go to college or qualifications to join the police force or what.  So you can add that in:

> I would like to know what qualifications I need *to apply*.

Great.  Now they know you want to apply for something.  But what do you want to apply for?  A membership in the club?  A credit card?  A job?

> I would like to know what qualifications I need to apply *for this job*.

Now, having said all that, let me suggest that when you join a new community, you might want to take a moment to find out [what it's about](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [how you should act](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before just jumping in and bugging people.  This question is actually much more suited to the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site than ELU.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have not yet applied for the job, the proper sentence would be:

> I would like to know what **qualifications I need to apply** for this job.

A-C are not quite correct because you never will *be applied* to a job. You may have already applied, but you won't *be applied.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on this site, but get the feeling this might get moved to English learners. In any case you don't need to use -- shouldn't use in fact -- the verb 'to be' in your sentence:

I would like to know what qualifications I need to apply for the job.

(The verb following the verb 'need' will use the infinitive form.)
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The context is a little unclear.

Assuming you are applying for the job, then you should say something like so.

I would like to know what << qualifications I need to apply >> for this job.

Or, depending on your personal style preference, possibly << qualifications I need in order to apply >>.